# JMeter - access current variable attributes in for each controller

Tags: jmeter

I have a For Each controller in Jmeter, which iterates a list of complex JSON objects, for example:

```
JSONObject{
   "field1": "value1",
   "field2": "value2",
   "field3": "value3"
}
```

during iterations I'm able to access the current complex object with for each, but I can't access inner values: I need to access to field1, field2 values.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using i.e. [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [Groovy language](https://groovy-lang.org/):

```
def field1 = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(vars.get('your-variable')).field1

vars.put('field1', field1)
```

or using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy):

```
${__groovy(new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(vars.get('your-variable')).field1,)}
```

More information:

- [JsonSlurper](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)